# Vim syntax match

Tags: vim, vim-syntax-highlighting

I am implementing a syntax highlight for a proprietary C expansion that we use in VIM.

The syntax is this:

```
int __event(foobar) my_foobar_function()
{
    //whatever
    if(foobar)
        // do something
}
```

Now what I would like to do is to highlight  `__event(foobar)`, so I wrote this:

```
syn region xREG start=/__event(/ end=/)/ contains=xFOO
syn keyword xFOO foobar contained

hi xREG ctermfg=darkblue
hi xFOO ctermfg=cyan
```

This highlights the `__event()` correctly, however, the foobar in `if(foobar)` also gets highlighted.

My question is how can I restrict the xFOO group to be highlighted ONLY in xREG and nowhere else.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you extend an existing syntax (like *C*), you need to consider the existing syntax items. The following line from `syntax/c.vim` causes the inclusion of your `xFOO` group via the `ALLBUT=`:

```
syn region  cParen      transparent start='(' end=')' end='}'me=s-1 contains=ALLBUT,cBlock,@cParenGroup,cCppParen,cErrInBracket,cCppBracket,cCppString,@Spell
```

Fortunately, it provides an extension point: You have to add your group to the `@cParenGroup` cluster:

```
syn cluster cParenGroup add=xFoo
```

That should do the trick!